# Repair data source for all layers simultaneously using QGIS

Tags: layers, qgis-2.12

In QGIS 2.12 i opened a map after i changed it location in the hard disk.

Hence, all layers must be repair. I know the option to fix every layer separate, but i didn't find an option to "repair data source" for all layers simultaneously, like in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 1):

No such option as far as I know.

Quick & dirty solution: Open QGIS project file with a text editor, search & replace.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin called "changeDataSource", you can download it from Plugin Manager. After installing the Plugin right click the target file and update its data source, or you click the icon in the toolbar and update the data source of all files.